# Contradiction in TISE of two-particle system $V(x_1-x_2)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

For this Hamiltonian, we have the classical Poisson bracket $\{H,p_1+p_2\}=0$. Quantising gives $$[H,P_1+P_2]=0.$$

Eigenvectors of $P_1+P_2$ are the functions $e^{i(p_1x_1+p_2x_2)}$. I say these are the eigenvectors because $$(-i\frac{d}{dx_1}-i\frac{d}{dx_2})e^{i(x_1p_1+x_2p_2)}=(p_1+p_2)e^{i(x_1p_1+x_2p_2)}.$$
These must also be the eigenvectors of $H$ because of the commutation relation.

But, all these eigenvectors are states of definite momentum (as they are also eigenvectors of $P_1$ ans $P_2$ individually). How can the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian have definite momentum when a potential is present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is that while the two operators $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{P}= \hat{P}_1+\hat{P}_2$ share a simultaneous eigenbasis, it doesn't have to be the same as the eigenbasis of states that look like $e^{i(p_1x_1+p_2x_2)}$.  This is because there is an *infinite* degeneracy for each subspace corresponding to total momentum eigenvalue $p$.  To see this, we note that
$$
e^{i(p_1x_1+p_2x_2)}
=
e^{i(p_1-p_2)r/2}e^{ipR}
=
e^{i(2p_1-p)r/2}e^{ipR}\,,\,,
$$
where $r=x_1-x_2$ it the relative coordinate, $R=(x_1+x_2)/2$ is the center-of-mass coordinate, and $p=p_1+p_2$.  Note that as long as $p=p_1+p_2$ is fixed, this is an eigenstate of $\hat{P}$, but we can integrate over, say $p_1$ and still have an eigenstate of $\hat{P}$, i.e.,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp_1\,c(p_1)e^{i(2p_1-p)r/2}e^{ipR}
=
e^{ipR}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp_1\,c(p_1)e^{i(2p_1-p)r/2}\,,
$$
is an eigenstate of $\hat{P}$ while being an eigenstate of neither $\hat{P}_1$ nor $\hat{P}_2$, generally speaking.  The eigenstates of the Hamiltonian will be of this general form.

---

This is very general situation.  You have three operators $\hat{X}$, $\hat{Y}$, and $\hat{Z}$.  They don't all mutually commute, because $[\hat{X},\hat{Z}]\neq0$, but $[\hat{X},\hat{Y}]=[\hat{Y},\hat{Z}]= 0$.  This means that it is impossible to find a simultaneous eigenbasis for all of them at once.  However, because $\hat{Y}$ commutes with $\hat{X}$, there exists a simultaneous eigenbasis that we might label as $\lvert x,y\rangle$.  Then, because $\hat{Y}$ also commutes with $\hat{Z}$, there must be basis of eigenstates of both of these operators. Eigenstates of $\hat{Z}$ can then be written as linear combinations of these states *with fixed* $y$, i.e.,
$$
\lvert y,z\rangle = \sum_x c_{x,z}\lvert x,z\rangle\,.
$$

Comment: I just clarified it. See the thing in written in the bracket. I meant that these are also eigenvectors of $P_1$ and $P_2$ individually. So these are states of definite individual momenta of the particles, and not just definite total momenta.

Comment: @RyderRude The answer is that the eigenstates are infinitely degenerate, and so the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian will be linear combinations of states of definite $p$.  I am updating my answer now.

Comment: @RyderRude See the updated post.  I am also working on adding more details.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really understand this edit. Is it, like, there are eigenstates even outside of the set I mentioned? And you wrote a way to construct those? Please write some intuitive argument to supplement this answer

Comment: What about now?  There's an extra section about the general case.  The point is that when there is degeneracy, there are different choices that you can make for your basis, because any linear combination of eigenvectors that have the same eigenvalue $p$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $p$!  However, these linear combinations are *not* necessarily eigenvectors of $\hat{P}_1$ and $\hat{P}_2$, because we have taken linear combinations of states with different values of $p_1$ and $p_2$.  The eigenstates of $\hat{H}$ will be such linear combinations.

Comment: Have you seen addition of angular momentum yet?  The same kind of thing occurs.  You have two spins $\hat{\vec{S}}_1$ and $\hat{\vec{S}}_2$, and you can form the sum of these two spins to get the total spin $\hat{S} = \hat{\vec{S}}_1+\hat{\vec{S}}_2$. A basis of angular momentum states for the combined systems is $\lvert s_1 m_{s,1} , s_2 m_{s,2}\rangle$, but it turns out that these are *not* generally eigenstates of total $\hat{S}^2$, because $\hat{S}^2$ doesn't commute with the $z$-components of the spin operators.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. This situation also appears in $L^2$, $L_z$, $L_x$, $L_y$.